# Pass a callback function from Visual Basic to C#

Tags: c#, vba, callback, com

I have a `.dll` written in C# and I use it in Visual Basic for making a Com object. I call C# functions from my Visual Basic code. I'm quite new to this technology and I encountered with such a problem. In C# code I have a method, that receives a callback function as a parameter, gets data from server then calls that callback function. Now I need to to call that function from my Visual Basic code and pass to it a callback.
I think it should look something like this

```
// C# dll
public bool GetDataFromServer(int someData1, Action<MyCustomType> callback, int someData2)
{
    // request to server, get data, create an object of MyCustomType
    // call callback and pass MyCustomType object to it as a parameter
}

// Visual Basic part
Public Sub DisplayData(ByRef resp As My_Dll.MyCustomType)
    ' do something with resp
End Sub

// call Dll method
My_Dll.GetDataFromServer(1, DisplayData, 2) ' I get a compile error
```

But I can't get it work, it event does not compile. I get a compilation error saying "Argument not optional". I've also tried to pass callback function with `AddressOf`, but I get an error again saying - "Invalid use of AddressOf operator".
Now my question is - what am I doing wrong? What is the correct way of passing a callback function from Visual Basic to C# and then get it invoked.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: How about using `async` and `await` instead of callbacks?

Comment: Actually I need a callback because I'm going to make a subscription. So my callback should be called again and again depending on server responses.

Comment: VBA has no delegates. Have you considered passing an object that C# can store and call when it's done?

Comment: @DanL but can I pass the `MyCustomObject` back to VBA?

Comment: You could use `Application.Run` to trigger the "callback".

Answer (score 0):

Anything containing generics is not visible to COM, so your `GetDataFromServer` with `Action<MyCustomType>` is not COM visible.  You must define a method on a non-generic class without generic type arguments of itself and without generic parameter or return types.

The usual way of passing a callback in COM is to pass an interface pointer with a method to be called.  Avoid the `AddressOf` approach, however feasible, it's really bad practice once you want the callback to work out-of-process.

A common trick with `IDispatch` objects is to define a class with a default method with DispId 0 ([`DISPID_VALUE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221242(v=vs.85).aspx)), which may be invoked by the COM server through `IDispatch::Invoke`.  In some languages, such as JScript, objects may be callable through this technique.

To see how you can do this in VB6/VBA, search for `VB_UserMemId`.  Essentially, you must edit the class file in its raw format (in VBA, you must export it) and add an attribute, such as:

```
Sub Call()
Attribute Call.VB_UserMemId = 0
End Sub
```

In VBA, you'd delete the class and import from the edited file.  The effect is that the `Call` method now has DispId 0.  You may call it whatever you want, but remember to edit both the `Sub` name and the `Attribute`.

In C#, I believe the only ways to achieve such call is with a `dynamic` variable with:

```
obj[0]
```

or through `Type.InvokeMember` or similar `IDispatch::Invoke` approaches:

```
obj.GetType().InvokeMember("", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, obj, null);
```

The latter is more reliable and you pass the arguments you want, while the former uses a misleading syntax and forces you to pass an argument.

In general, if you control the whole situation and you don't need callable objects, just go for a plain method.

Regarding the `AddressOf` error, this operator works on module procedures and functions, so the error you see is probably because `DisplayOptionQuotes` is a method.